# Python MySQLdb issues (TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str)

Tags: python, insertion, mysql-python

I am trying  to do the following insert operation:

```
cursor.execute("""
                    insert into tree (id,parent_id,level,description,code,start,end)
                    values (%d,%d,%d,%s,%s,%f,%f)
                    """, (1,1,1,'abc','def',1,1)
                    )
```

The structure of my MYSQL table is:

```
id int(255),
parent_id int(255),
level int(11),
description varchar(255),
code varchar(255),
start decimal(25,4),
end decimal(25,4)
```

However when I run my program, I get the error

> "  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 151, in execute
>       query = query % db.literal(args)
>
> TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str"

Answer (score 182, accepted):

The format string is not really a normal Python format string. You must always use `%s` for all fields.

refer [official document](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute):

> If args is a list or tuple, %s can be used as a **placeholder** in the query. If args is a dict, %(name)s can be used as a placeholder in the query.

-> that is: here `%s` is **NOT formatter**, but **is a placeholder**

Comment: Saved me from wasting several more hours !! Thank you very much ! Is there any other way to handle prepared statements? Because this really does not seem be a prepared statement so to speak.

Comment: Use oursql. It can do real parameterization, instead of fake client-side one MySQLdb does.

Comment: Darn. I wasted a solid three hours trying to understand why `%d` is causing error..

Comment: I encountered this problem too. 我刚才也遇到了这个问题,看到回答,我就知道怎么做了

Comment: You must always use %s for all fields. 这句话最实用

Comment: I had to convert decimal values e.g. 1.52456 to string str(value) and then I could use %s. %d did not work even if I converted value to decimal using decimal.Decimal(). Finally I got this working.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I trust you, and this solution worked, but I'd prefer to know an authoritative source and why they chose to mandate this.

Comment: @Evan The source code itself. It's just a custom string interpolation implementation. It resembles Python, but isn't the normal Python. This is done to escape the value to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error, but it was for a different reason. The problem was that the string included a '%' and that confused Python:

```
TemplateStr = '[....] % discount rate  [....]  %s and %s
print TemplateStr % ('abc', 'def')
```

Python interpreted that "% discount" as "%d" and kept complaining because I was feeding it a string  ('abc'), not a number.

It took me a long time to figure it out!

(The solution is to type %% instead of %.)

Answer (score 3):

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46517683/1564659

I finally use `%s` even for floats and digits. It will be converted right away when inserted to the table and SQL detected the table data type

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
cursor.execute("""
                    insert into tree (id,parent_id,level,description,code,start,end)
                    values (%s,%s,%s,'%s','%s',%s,%s)
                    """%(1,1,1,'abc','def',1,1)
                    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Since his data is in integer or decimal format how can you use %s which is usually used for string format %d or %i should be used for integer or decimal values.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you saw that type of errors, should use type() function for checking the types of values or variables...., and will see type is - 'str'. Means python takes all the values in strings (By default data type is string). That's why the error said %d is for numbers, Not for the strings. So consider %s in python for every types of field.