# MySQLdb Python insert %d and %s

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Precursor:

```
MySQL Table created via:
CREATE TABLE table(Id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Param1 VARCHAR(50))
```

Function:

```
.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES(%d,%s)", (int(id), string)
```

Output:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not a str
```

I'm not sure what's going on here or why I am not able to execute the command. This is using MySQLdb in Python. `.execute` is performed on a cursor object.

EDIT:

The question: [Python MySQLdb issues (TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785154/python-mysqldb-issues)
says that you must use `%s` for all fields. Why might this be? Why does this command work?

```
.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES(%s,%s)", (int(id), string)
```

Comment: You are missing a `%` and `)` - `.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES(%d,%s)"% (int(id), string))`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As the whole query needs to be in a string format while execution of query so `%s` should be used...

After query is executed integer value is retained.

So your line should be.

```
.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES(%s,%s)", (int(id), string))
```

Explanation is [here](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples)

Comment: I have received errors on python 2.7 with syntax like that.  Atleast on my side if a parametized %s is expected my python expects a string value there, and I've had to convert it to string like str(someVal).

Comment: @Kickass - You might want to check to see if you have a string interpolation operator (%) separating your SQL INSERT string and your values tuple instead of a comma.

Comment: @xor How do I do this with just a single column? I have my ID as Autoincrement. so I need not add it. Only the field "`Param1`" (as in example here) needs to be added. `mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable Param1 VALUES %s", (name))`. But it keeps saying Syntax error at `%s`. I also tried as `(%s)`. No use

Comment: @Priya I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309096/cant-insert-single-column-value-in-python-using-mysql

Answer (score 10):

The format string is not really a normal Python format string. You must always use %s for all fields

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution on [dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html). In short, use a `dict`, not a `tuple` in the second parameter of `.execute()`:

```py
add_salary = ("INSERT INTO salaries "
              "(emp_no, salary, from_date, to_date) "
              "VALUES (%(emp_no)s, %(salary)s, %(from_date)s, %(to_date)s)")

data_salary = {
  'emp_no': emp_no,
  'salary': 50000,
  'from_date': tomorrow,
  'to_date': date(9999, 1, 1),
}

cursor.execute(add_salary, data_salary)
```

Answer (score -4):

You missed a `'%'` in string formatting

```
"(INSERT INTO table VALUES(%d,%s)"%(int(id), string))
```

Comment: i am sorry this s downvoted, but it is a way forward the answer `("INSERT INTO table VALUES(%d,'%s')"%(int(id), string))` you should edit it

Comment: It's much safer to get in the habit of using the parameters to the `cursor.execute` function to eliminate risk of injection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/775399/6284025