# Can't insert single column value in python using MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7

I have a single column table. I need to insert values in this column. The program runs correctly without errors. But when I check the database, nothing gets inserted. When I added another column to the code and table, the program inserts data correctly. Can you tell me how to insert data for a single column table?
This is the single column code that does not insert anything to the table.

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost",
                  user="root",
                  passwd="123",
                  db="dbname")
cursor = conn.cursor()
x=100
try:
    sql="""INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES ('%s')"""
    cursor.execute(sql, (x))
    conn.commit()
except:
    conn.rollback()

conn.close()
```

This is the two columns code.

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost",
                  user="root",
                  passwd="123",
                  db="dbname")
cursor = conn.cursor()
x=100
y=2
try:
    sql="""INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES ('%s','%s')"""
    cursor.execute(sql, (x,y))
    conn.commit()
except:
    conn.rollback()

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to lose the quotes around `%s`, after that you need to know that the second argument to `cursor.execute()` is a tuple, and that a one-tuple is written:

```
(item,)
```

note the comma. The solution is then:

```
sql="""INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES (%s)"""
cursor.execute(sql, (x,))
```

Comment: I tried this `sql="""INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES (%s)"""
    cursor.execute(sql, (x,))`. It runs but it does not insert the data to DB.

Comment: Your two column version is correct if you remove the quotes around the place holders.

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of these:

1. Don't use `'%s'`, you can use `?` instead
2. Instead of `'%s'`, just use `%s` without quotes

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
sql="""INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES ({});""".format(x)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Please don't forget to explain / comment your code, and provide relevant documentation [from review]

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. Try to explain how your code solves OP's problem. Others that find this question may not be as experienced as you; help them to understand your solution.

Comment: This strategy is also a sql-injection waiting to happen (although in this particular case you'll probably get a sql syntax-error first).