# Pymysql- issue with adding mixed types of data into database record

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

I am trying to write a function that adds a record to database using pymysql. It worked when I used strings, however when I try to mix strings and integer it does not work.

```
def dodawanie_do_bazy(a,b,c,e):
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                        user='root',
                                        password='',
                                        db='dbprojekt',
                                        charset='utf8mb4',
                                        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.SSDictCursor);
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql="INSERT INTO `Czlonek` (`imie`,`nazwisko`,`wydzial`,`telefon`,`mail`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%d,%s)"; 
            cursor.execute(sql,(a,b,c,456798136,e));
        connection.commit()         
    finally:
        connection.close();
```

## ERROR is TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: Change %d  to %s and it should work for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20463628/11107506

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error

> ERROR is TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

evidently states, it needs to be of `%s` format instead of `%d`. The format string is not really a Python format string to use `%d`. You must always use `%s` for all fields

Simply changing this from `VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%d,%s)` to `VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)` will solve your problem.