# Query to insert data in mysql table contains foreign key

Tags: python, mysql

I am very new to Mysql and dumping a file in db using python. I'm having 2 tables
The file format is:

```
id name sports
1 john baseball
2 mary Football
```

like  student & Sports
Student table

```
id    name
 1     John
 2     Mary
```

here id is primary key

& in sports table

```
stu_id sports_title

1      Baseball
2      Football
```

and here stu_id is foreign key  reference with student table

and my problem is

```
query="insert into sports (stu_id,name)VALUES (%d,%s)"
            ("select id from student where id=%d,%s")
#words[0]=1 ,words[2]=Baseball

args=(words[0],words[2])
cursor.execute(query,args)
```

upon executing this code, I'm facing

```
  "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Comment: Please elaborate what `words` is.

Comment: ... and what's going on with `query`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I guess `words` is the fields of the lines from the file shown at the top.

Comment: @Barmar if you have to guess, the question is incomplete. It could've as well been the rows, but the edit made it clear that it is a row.

Comment: At least with the mysql.connector DB-API driver [all placeholders should be either %s or %(name)s](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), depending on how you pass the args. There's no distinction between numbers, strings, etc. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785154/python-mysqldb-issues-typeerror-d-format-a-number-is-required-not-str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use both `VALUES` and `SELECT` as the source of the data in `INSERT`. You use `VALUES` if the data is literals, you use `SELECT` if you're getting it from another table. If it's a mix of both, you use `SELECT` and put the literals into the `SELECT` list.

```
query = """
    INSERT INTO sports (stu_id, sports_title)
    SELECT id, %s
    FROM student
    WHERE name = %s
"""
args = (words[2], words[1])
cursor.execute(args)
```

Or, since the file contains the student ID, you don't need `SELECT` at all.

```
query = "INSERT INTO sports(stu_id, sports_title) VALUES (%d, %s)"
args = (words[0], words[1])
cursor.execute(args)
```