# :TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str: even numbers were given in python pandas

Tags: python, mysql, parameterized-query

I am trying to update the values in the mysql database using parameterized queries. But after running the below code:

```
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM df LIMIT 3', con=db_connection)
print(df.shape)
labels = ('I1','I2','I3')
ids = (123456,123457,123458)
data = (labels,ids)
cursor = db_connection.cursor()
for i in df.id:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE df SET label = %s WHERE id= %d",data)
    db_connection.commit()
db_connection.close()
```

**I am getting this error:**
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

The data type of 'id' is int in database. And I am providing numbers only. don't know why it is throwing such error...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python MySQLdb issues (TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785154/python-mysqldb-issues-typeerror-d-format-a-number-is-required-not-str)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help AlEmerich,
I was giving data in this format

```
labels = ('I1','I2','I3')
ids = (123456,123457,123458)
data = (labels,ids)
data
(('I1', 'I2', 'I3'), (123456, 123457, 123458))
```

But when I made it in this way:

```
data = (('I1',123456),('I2',123457),('I3',123458))
```

It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE df SET label = %s WHERE id= %d",data)
```

You have a tuple of tuple in data. It seems that the compiler tries to format the 'I2' variable in '%d'.

Comment: I don't have the time to setup a database to test but you can try something like that:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE df SET label = %s WHERE id= %d",(data[0],data[1])).
I wil edit the answer if it works.

Comment: Nervermind, I don't think I was right after some digging in the documentation. Can you try to replace %d with %s ? According to this link (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), it seems the %d is not required even for a int.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using flask_sqlalchemy and I made a mistake creating the model

I wrote

```
class LocationModel(db.Model):
      address = db.String(db.String(50))
```

instead

```
class LocationModel(db.Model):
      address = db.Column(db.String(50))
```